Textfield Sometimes Highlighted When getFocusInWindow() Called
I have a vertical BoxLayout with a few JTextfields. Whenever one of the fields is edited, I would like the field to come to the top: I do this by removing the field and re-adding it to the top. However, when this is done, the textfield loses focus. Therefore, whenever a textfield is edited, I call requestFocusInWindow() on it. However, if the user's caret was previously (before the removal and re-adding) on the end of the line, and only in this instance, the whole textfield will be highlighted. If the user's caret was anywhere before the end of the line, this does not happen. This is an unwanted behaviour - the cursor should just stay at the end if it was there previously, and no highlighting should take place. An example is provided below. Try editing any of the textfields.
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        var frame = new JFrame();
        var panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        frame.add(panel);

        var text1 = new JTextField();
        var text2 = new JTextField();
        var text3 = new JTextField();
        moveUpOnEdit(panel, text1, text2, text3);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void moveUpOnEdit(JPanel container, JTextField... textFields) {
        for (JTextField textField : textFields) {
            container.add(textField);
            textField.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
                public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {changedUpdate(e);}

                public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {changedUpdate(e);}

                public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                    container.remove(textField);
                    container.add(textField, 0);
                    container.revalidate();
                    textField.requestFocusInWindow();
                }
            });
        }
    }

}

I have tried:

using UIManager.put("TextComponent.selectAllOnFocusPolicy", "never");
messing with the caret position
messing with the highlighter

Nothing has thus far worked.

I'm not clear on what the desired behavior is. Please clarify -- what exactly do you want to happen in this situation.

If you want the text field selected, have you tried calling textField.selectAll() on it? Conversely, if you want none of the text selected, you could call textField.setCaretPosition(0);  and textField.moveCaretPosition(0);

I would like it not to become highlighted, as all the text within the field is replaced if you start typing while it is highlighted.

Then set the caret position as noted above.

I tried calling both of those after and before requestFocusInWindow(), however that does not resolve the issue.

I am not able to reproduce what I think is your unwanted behavior. I am using a Windows 11 machine and Java 19.

I also don't have a problem on a Windows machine. If you are using a different OS maybe try wrapping the requestFocusInWindow() statement in an invokeLater() to make sure the code is executed after the layout of the components is finished.

Thanks - I tested the same code on a Linux machine, and the bug was not reproduced. Actually, running UIManager.setLookAndFeel("javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel"); resolves the issue; it seems that the problem lies in Apple's Aqua LAF. Should I log a bug report, or is this intentional?

From a user experience standpoint, yanking away a text field while the user is typing in it is disconcerting, and makes the software seem rude.  How would you feel if someone yanked away a sheet of paper while you were busy writing on it?  You might want to use a FocusListener instead.
